# Testing non public routes results in KeyError

Tags: authentication, integration-testing, keyerror, crystal-lang, amber-framework

i am new to Crystal and Amber and i have an Issue with testing non public routes. I used the Amber authentication generator and afterwards geneated a scaffold for a Job entity and added related routes to routes :auth block.
When i open up a browser and try to go directly to a job route everything works as expected and i get redirected to the sign in page.

But when i execute the generated tests for JobsController i get the following error:

```
1) JobControllerTest renders job index template
       Missing hash key: :auth (KeyError)
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/hash.cr:1030:9 in ‘[]’
         from lib/amber/src/amber/pipes/pipeline.cr:19:15 in ‘call’
         from lib/garnet_spec/src/garnet_spec/controller/test.cr:25:7 in ‘process_request’
         from spec/controllers/job_controller_spec.cr:20:1 in ‘get’
         from spec/controllers/job_controller_spec.cr:39:5 in ‘->’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/primitives.cr:255:3 in ‘internal_run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/example.cr:33:16 in ‘run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/context.cr:18:23 in ‘internal_run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/context.cr:330:7 in ‘run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/context.cr:18:23 in ‘internal_run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/context.cr:147:7 in ‘run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/spec/dsl.cr:270:7 in ‘->’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/primitives.cr:255:3 in ‘run’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/crystal/main.cr:45:14 in ‘main’
         from ../../.asdf/installs/crystal/0.35.1/src/crystal/main.cr:114:3 in ‘main’
```

**routes.cr**

```
routes :auth do
 ...
 resources "jobs", JobController
end
```

**JobControllerTest.cr**

```
...
class JobControllerTest < GarnetSpec::Controller::Test
  getter handler : Amber::Pipe::Pipeline

  def initialize
    @handler = Amber::Pipe::Pipeline.new
    @handler.build :web do
      plug Amber::Pipe::Error.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Session.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Flash.new
    end
    @handler.prepare_pipelines
  end
end

describe JobControllerTest do
  subject = JobControllerTest.new

  it “renders job index template” do
    Job.clear
    response = subject.get “/jobs” # -> line 39 where the error happens
    response.status_code.should eq(302)
    response.body.should contain(“jobs”)
  end
end
...
```

I didn't find any information in Ambers documentation and neither on Google. My questions are the following:

- **How am i supposed to provide the auth data? And why do i have at all since the application redirects when logged out?**
- **For controller specs Is there any test helper that signs user in so that it is possible to
  test with authenticated users?**

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to include the auth handler in the initialize function?

```
@handler.build :auth do
    plug Authenticate.new
end
```

**[Update]** Added pointers to add login tests.

To test authenticated routes, you can use System tests as documented here in https://docs.amberframework.org/amber/guides/testing/system-tests

I don't see much documentation for all the available API calls to do the system tests. But from this code I understand once page loads you can fill in login and password and simulate the click event. https://github.com/amberframework/garnet-spec/blob/master/src/garnet_spec/system_test.cr

```
fill(:class_name, "login", "test_username")
fill(:class_name, "password", "test_pass")
click(:class_name, "login-button")
```

I have not tested the code, updated the comment here based on the docs available.

Comment: Thank you very much. This leads to what i have expected. A redirect instead of an error. Can you also help me with my second question on how to authenticat a user in tests?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you. This would work but it is rather slow because of the login request needed for every test. I am looking for a test helper that bypasses the login flow and can be used in controller specs.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, if you are using the basic Auth that comes with Amber I added the following to my `spec_helper.cr` and was able to do controller tests with authenticated users by inheriting from the class.  It does require the `crystagiri` shard so that you are able to get the csrf_token.

```
require "../spec_helper"
require "crystagiri"


def login_params(csrf_token)
  params = [] of String
  params << "email=admin@example.com"
  params << "password=password"
  params << "_csrf=#{csrf_token}"
  params.join("&")
end

def create_user
    user = User.new(email: "admin@example.com", first_name:"Test", last_name:"User")
    user.password = "password"
    user.save
    user
end

def get_csrf_token(response_body)
  html = Crystagiri::HTML.new response_body
  csrf_token = String.new
  html.where_tag("input") do |back| 
    csrf_token = back.node.attributes[2].content
    break
  end

  csrf_token
end

class ApplicationControllerTest < GarnetSpec::Controller::Test
  getter handler : Amber::Pipe::Pipeline
  getter current_user = User.new
  getter csrf_token = String.new
  setter current_user

  def initialize
    @handler = Amber::Pipe::Pipeline.new

    @handler.build :web do
      plug Citrine::I18n::Handler.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Error.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Logger.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Session.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Flash.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::CSRF.new

      plug CurrentUser.new
    end

    @handler.build :auth do
      plug Citrine::I18n::Handler.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Error.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Logger.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Session.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::Flash.new
      plug Amber::Pipe::CSRF.new

      plug CurrentUser.new
      plug Authenticate.new
    end
    

    @handler.prepare_pipelines
    @current_user = create_user
  end

  def login_user
    response = get "/signin"
    @csrf_token = get_csrf_token(response.body)
    post "/session", body: login_params(csrf_token), headers: HTTP::Headers{"Cookie" => response.headers["Set-Cookie"]}
  end
end
```

And then in your `class_controller_spec.cr` you would have something like the following for when you need the user to be logged in before making a request

```
class AccountControllerTest < ApplicationControllerTest
 
end

describe AccountControllerTest do
  subject = AccountControllerTest.new

  it "renders account index template" do
    subject.current_user = create_user
    response_headers = subject.login_user.headers
    response = subject.get "/accounts", headers: HTTP::Headers{"Cookie" => response_headers["Set-Cookie"]}

    response.status_code.should eq(200)
    response.body.should contain("accounts")
  end
end
```

Hope that helps if you are still looking for a solution!